# Не срабатывает сохранение картинки при первом нажатии на кнопку камеры

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Подскажите, кто знает, не могу разобраться, в чем дело. При нажатии кнопки камеры происходит событие:

```
private void takePicture() {
    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, null, jpegCallback);

    shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            camera.startPreview();
        }
    };
    // запись файла         
    jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            if (data != null) {
                mydata = data;
                done(); // сохранение изображения
                camera.startPreview();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

На экране появляется изображение, однако оно не сохраняется и не срабатывает `startPreview`. Только после второго нажатия кнопки происходит сохранение изображение и нормально работает `prewiew`.

Answer (score 2):

Ты передаешь колбэки до того, как инициализировал их. А на второй раз они уже инициализированы, поэтому на второй раз срабатывает как надо.

Правильно так:

```
private void takePicture() {

    if (shutterCallback == null) {
        shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
           public void onShutter() {
               camera.startPreview();
           }
        };
    }
    // запись файла

    if (jpegCallback == null) {
        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
           public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                if (data != null) {
                    mydata = data;
                    done(); // сохранение изображения
                    camera.startPreview();
               }
            }
        };
    }

    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, null, jpegCallback);
```

}